# jQuery get attribute from dynamic tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html

```
<div class="form-new"><input name="a1" /></div>
<div class="form-new"><input name="a2" /></div>
<div class="form-new"><input name="a4" /></div>
<div class="form-new"><input name="a3" /></div>

...
```

it dynamic  so I want use jquery to get biggest number on the end of the name of input(in this example, it will be a4 ), plz tell me how to do this, sorry for my bad english

Comment: `$('.form-new input').last().attr('name')`

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "highest"? Is that the topmost one on  the form? Or the one with the biggest number on the end of the name?

Comment: yes, it biggest number on the end of the name

Comment: you can use also  $('.form-new:last input').attr('name')

Comment: Thank everyone, but it not work if <div class="form-new"><input name="a4" /></div> before <div class="form-new"><input name="a3" /></div>

I want biggest number on the end of the name, not the last input,plz help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var maxVal = -1;        // set to the minimum possible value
var maxInput;
$('.form-new input').each(function (i, e) {
    var val = parseInt($(e).attr('name').match(/\d+$/)[0]);    // gets the number at the end of "name" attribute value
    if (val > maxVal) {
        maxVal = val;
        maxInput = $(e);
    }
});

// maxInput holds the jQuery object of the input with max value at the end of "name" attribute
```

Comment: @Moogs I know. It's up to the OP to add the required validations as I'm only dealing with the cases he mentioned in his question. I don't even know what to do if there're no digits. What if there's no name attribute at all? It'll also error, but what should I do then?.. It's up to the OP. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

Sort the values in div and display the last one.

```js
var inputList = $('input').sort(function (a, b) {

      var contentA =$(a).attr('name');
      var contentB =$(b).attr('name');
      return (contentA > contentB);
   })

var totalInputItems = inputList.length;

alert($(inputList[totalInputItems-1]).attr('name'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-new"><input name="a1" /></div>
<div class="form-new"><input name="a2" /></div>
<div class="form-new"><input name="a4" /></div>
<div class="form-new"><input name="a3" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just write it up as below:

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/h9bqwjum/2/)**

```
var ip=$('.form-new input');
var numbers=[];
var maxNum=0;
$.each(ip,function(index,value){
    numbers.push([value["name"].split("a")[1],value]); //storing along with control so that you can refer in in future if you want
});

$.each(numbers,function(index,value){
     if(value[0]>parseInt(maxNum))
     {
          maxNum=value[0];
     }
});
alert("a"+maxNum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla JS

```
var largest = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.form-new')).reduce(function (acc, el) {
    var name = el.querySelector('input').getAttribute('name');
    return int(name) > int(acc) ? name : acc;
});

function int(s) { return parseInt(~~(s+'').replace(/.*[^\d](\d+)$/g,'$1')); }
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/j91x5asd/8/**

Comment: Just a small hint: the OP wants `biggest number on the end of the name`, but your code removes all non-digits and uses the remaining numbers. So if `name="a1b23"` your code will evaluate it to 123 while it should be just 23

Comment: Why not just `str.match(/\d+$/)` ? .. It's still Vanilla JS